# Is it possible to export * and default from another module in a single statement?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

### Situtation

I have a module `moduleA` with both `default` and named exports:

```
// Module A
export {
  A1 as default,
  A2,
  A3,
};
```

In another module `moduleB` I want to export (aggregate) everything from `moduleA` (both `default` and named exports). I did this:

```
// Module B
export * from "moduleA";
```

Then in another module `moduleC` I imported `moduleB`'s `default` export, which I expected to be `default` export of module A:

```
// Module C
import ModuleB from "moduleB";
```

But `ModuleB` got resolved to `undefined`.

I fixed this by changing module B to below and it works as expected:

```
// Module B
export { default } from "moduleA";
export * from "moduleA";
```

### Question

Can I somehow do my exports in module B in a single line? Something like  below (which is invalid syntax).

```
export { default, * } from moduleA;
```

*Aside*: Why does `export * from <module>` not export `default` import/export?

Comment: "In JavaScript you cannot use these reserved words as variables, labels, or function names: ... `default`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

From the [ecma](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getexportednames) spec, `export * from "moduleA";` does not re-export the default binding from the referenced module.

[There's a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-export-ns-from), currently on stage one, that may allow you to do that tho.

Comment: Thanks. That's as clear as it can get. I'm only not sure how `moduleC` import would look like, if `moduleB` would use the syntax currently in proposal: `export * as moduleB from "moduleA";`. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe the snippet below is the pattern you are looking for:

```
// Module A
export {
  A1 as default,
  A2,
  A3,
};


// Module B
export * as moduleA from 'moduleA;'


// Module C
import * as moduleB from 'moduleB;' /* This is known as a 'namespace import' */
```

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need. But then when I use it in my React Native project I'm given an error `Support for the experimental syntax exportNamespaceFrom isn't currently enabled`. Is this syntax in the JavaScript standard?

Comment: I've always wondered, in the simple case, can you just skip the intermediary and  export * from Module B, then import * from Module B into Module C? You don't need A, and B is just minified JavaScript you don't want to sort into named exports. But you want to modularize it and import it into C (your global module), to get strict and organize your code.